# How to get fast key where effeciently the key where value is dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {"a": {"order":1, "item":"x"}, "b": {"order": 2, "item":"y"}}
```

Here, highest value for order is 2, so I'd like to retrieve the key "b"

Any idea for the most efficient, fastest way please?

The most i could do

```
m = 0 
result = None 
for k,v in d.items(): 
    if v["order"] > m: 
        m = v["order"] 
        result = k
```

Comment: What does your current slow inefficient way look like?

Comment: m = 0
result = None
for k,v in d.items():
    if v["order"] > m:
        m = v["order"]
        result = k

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt.

Comment: An easy way: `max((v["order"], k) for k, v in d.items())[1]`

Comment: Maybe more efficient: `max(zip(map(operator.itemgetter("order"), d.values()), d))[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, using `max()`:

```py
d = {"a": {"order": 1, "item": "x"}, "b": {"order": 2, "item": "y"}}

print(max(d, key=lambda k: d[k]["order"]))
```

Prints:

```
b
```